# 3rd party website authentication libraries (like openid)

Tags: php, authentication, openid, facebook

I'm building a website that will require user registration and logon.

I would like to use the facebook connect to let people create a basic account and to log on without having to create a local account themselves - and let them fill in more profile details when they want to.

What other 3rd party authorizations systems are there? Clearly openid is one option. And google seem to have a system too for loging onto other sites with your google logon. Are there any other systems? Does microsoft have one for msn logons? I found some hints but was unable to find any details.

Anyway, the programming question is are there any php libraries that will do this for me across a range of providers? I see ones for facebook and OpenID but I've not seen any library in php that abstracts away the differences? Before I program my own solution are there any libraries for this that I've not managed to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that Facebook is likely to become an openid provider in the near future (for some value of near).

If you really want EVERYTHING abstracted for you, [JanRain](http://www.janrain.com/) takes care of exactly that task for you as a hosted service. The free version provides enough functionality to get started, and then if your app takes off, you can pay a bit for more functionality down the road.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm not really looking for a hosted service just a library that abstracts away some of the differences between services.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I don't use it either. Good to know about though.

Comment: Yes it is. +1 for a helpful and relevent answer even though it's not what I need